# How to step into C/C++ DLL from C# application while debugging

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging, step-into

I have two project in my solution: C/C++ Win32 DLL and some C# application.

What I have to do to be able to step into DLL while debugging?

I switched on all debugging options in C++ project's settings and copied to C# application root next files: MyLib.dll, MyLib.pdb, vc90.pdb, vc90.idb, but it doesn't helped.

What additional actions have I to carry out?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Have you turned on Enable Unmanaged Code Debugging in your C# project?

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you. Oh, I don't even want to think about how much time I've spent looking for this on my own.

Comment: VS2012 (and probably VS2010 update): the option is now named  `Enable native code debugging`  it is still the first option below `Enable Debuggers`

Comment: As an add-on, you need to set this option both on the c# project from where the pinvoke function is called and also on the managed entry point (project) of your application.

Answer (score 10):

If you are attaching a debugger through **Debug > Attach To Process**, before clicking "Attach" in the "Attach to Process" dialog, make sure to **select the appropriate code type** to which the debugger can be attached.

[image]