# Stepping into a P/Invoke call in disassemby view

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, pinvoke, step-into

My C# code is calling an unmanaged third-party library function via P/Invoke, and the unmanaged function is having some strange side effects. I want to debug into it and see what it's doing.

If I debug my C# code, and try to "Step Into" the P/Invoke call, it steps over instead. No surprise there -- I expected that; it doesn't have the source for this DLL, and I didn't tell it I was okay with seeing the disassembly view.

So I switch the debugger to disassembly view (Debug > Windows > Disassembly). Now I see the individual x86 instructions in my JITted code. Again I try to step into the P/Invoke call. Again, it steps over instead -- even though I clearly told it to Step Into an x86 CALL instruction. How hard is it to step into an x86 CALL?

My Googling thus far has shown me a couple of options that can affect this, and I've already set them:

- In Tools > Options > Debugging > General, "Enable Just My Code" is unchecked.
- In Project > Properties > Debug tab, "Enable unmanaged code debugging" is checked.

No good. Visual Studio still refuses to step in.

I don't have a PDB for the third-party DLL, but that shouldn't matter. I don't care about source code or symbol information. (Well, actually they'd be really nice, but I already know I'm not going to get them.) Visual Studio can do x86 debugging (that's what the Disassembly view is *for*), and all I want to do is step into the x86 code.

What else do I need to do to get VS to allow me to step into the x86 instructions inside a P/Invoke call?

Comment: It's been a few years since I tried to do this, but as I recall, no, I never did get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390407/pinvokestackimbalance-c-call-to-unmanaged-c-function) may help you solve the problem:
(by Graviton)

```
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl
```

Also [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/06/02/424595.aspx) mentions that you need to detach managed debugger and re-attach unmanaged when crossing the boundaries. You might need to check the capabilities of mixed debugger and it's preferences from MSDN.

And finally, using [Ed Dore'](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/91232ee3-a70c-43e4-b9f2-f8ff860c60ca/) answer:

> Under Tools.Options dialog, select the
>   Debugging category, and make sure the
>   "Enable Just My Code" setting is
>   unchecked.  From the Project
>   properties, select the Debug tab, and
>   then ensure that "Enable unmanaged
>   code debugging" is checked.
>
> Once you've got these squared away,
>   you should get the mixed mode
>   debugging support working.
>
> Also, if you use "Debug.Attach To
>   Process" , be sure to hit the
>   "Select..." button in the "Attach To
>   Process" dialog, and select both
>   Managed and Native debugging support.

Comment: None of these help step into calls to framework methods in VS2017/Win10 :(

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would try is going from C# to C++/CLI code, and then from C++ to the third-party code.  Once you're in C++ (and free of the P/Invoke infrastructure), you might have better luck with the disassembly view.

Comment: I know pretty much nothing about writing C++/CLI code... got any links that could help get me started with this strategy?

Answer (score 1):

In your C# project properties, in the Debug tab, check Enable native code debugging. Worked for me in VS 2012.

Credit goes to [billb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/765501/785745).

Also, since it's a third party library, ensure Enable Just My Code is unchecked in Options > Debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I was debugging a C# exe that called my own C++ dll via PInvoke, all part of the same solution.  Enabling native code debugging in my c# project allowed me to debug my C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue today.
What helped in my case was to run Visual Studio as administrator.

My setup:

- Visual Studio 2019
- Windows 10