# Call C++ native dll from C# code

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I wrote total native C++ code dll and I want to call his method thru C# code using P/Invoke. 
Do I need to change something in the properties of the native dll for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

P/Invoking requires the stdcall convention. So look if all your functions declarations are preceeded by __stdcall. Otherwise the stack gets corrupted.

Also look at [PInvokeStackImbalance C# call to unmanaged C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390407/pinvokestackimbalance-c-sharp-call-to-unmanaged-c-function)

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to change the properties of the DLL itself, but you need to make sure that the calling conventions match with those used in C#. Then you need to declare your callable functions in C# with matching argument and return types of those in C++.

Now you can call your functions in C#.

Besides the calling convention thing for your C++ functions, it should be fairly easy.