# "Attach to Process" instead of "Local Windows Debugger"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I updated my version of Visual Studio Express 2012 and now I get "Attach to Process" instead of the "Local Windows Debugger" option which I had previously. So I can no longer run/debug my project. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Fix the heading. But it's funny now)

Comment: This is Off-topic to SO isn't it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765481/how-to-step-into-c-c-dll-from-c-sharp-application-while-debugging

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution to this problem is - to exit Visual studio. Make sure the *.SLN points to the proper project location
And then delete the "obj" folder from the file explorer.
Restart VS.

Answer (score 0):

Go to %appdata% and delete the visual studios folder