# Local windows debugger replaced with attach and cannot run and debug my program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

For some ambiguous reason MS visual studio 2013 has decided to replace local windows debugger with the word attach next to the big green play button. I can no longer run and debug my program that I am trying to work on at the moment. I have tried tooth and nail for the past hour to fix the issue with no resolve. I would simply like to know how to get the "local windows debugger" back if that is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976496/attach-to-process-instead-of-local-windows-debugger)

Comment: I have the same problem and could not solve my problem with the solution given in that linked question. Perhaps I'm dumb, but I just don't see anything on that msdn page that shows how to get the debugger back.

Comment: The link provided above also did not help me. I managed to find the solution to my problem on my own. I figured out that I was opening the wrong file in my project folder. Try opening the file in you project folder with the file type: Microsoft Visual Studio Solution or C++ Source. Hope this solves you problems.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem, every time I went to open up my file like I normally do it came up with a plain page and instead of the start button it was the attach button.

To solve it all I did was, opened my projects, located where the folder was for the programme I wanted to access.

Then I opened the .snl and when the blank screen and the attach button appeared again I went to the view drop down menu and clicked on solution explorer. Then it opened to my right and I opened the tab that had the console name on it and finally I clicked on file name which I had named.

By doing that my code appeared and I was able to start my programme. To prevent this in the future I pinned my file to the top of the bar so it would stay like that once it was closed.I hope this was of some help.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me before and I found that if you accidentally saved the .sln file the last time you closed Visual Studio, the .vcxproj file will not let you run and debug.

If this is your issue, you should see a .sln file in the same directory as your project file. Delete the .sln file, then open your .vcxproj project. The normal menu options should reappear.